SSMS refuses to start 2
This question is pretty similar with this one - SSMS refuses to start. However, a completely different *.dll is in question. Applying the solution from that answer doesn't help. I ran ssms.exe with logging and this is the error entry:
<entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2024/08/26 09:09:04.056</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [Task Scheduler Package]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The keyset is not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090019)&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The keyset is not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090019)&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; ---&gt; System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80090019): The keyset is not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090019)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateAppDomainManager()&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80090019): The keyset is not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090019)</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
  </entry>

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this. The issue started all of a sudden after I hadn't touched my laptop for a month.
Reparing the installation doesn't help.
Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't help. I even tried removing the shared components in between installation hoping it is one of them.
Installing previous versions of ssms yields the same result.
Clearing app data for the application doesn't help as per some recommendations.
If I open procmon.exe and monitor ssms.exe process I can see that this assembly is in fact found and loaded. I am not sure if there is some other referenced assembly missing.

What version of SSMS were you initially experiencing this issue with?

With 20.1. I updated to 20.2 and then I side installed 19.0. Same results.

Out of curiosity, can you get SSMS 18 to run successfully? I haven't upgraded from 18 yet because of the rampant bugs that were in 19 (and now we've already moved onto 20).

I actually found out what the issue was via a similar issue for VS. Recently I was configuring Default CSP as a part of our migration to new way of code signing and this seems to be messing things up. Running sn -c will reset the default CSP and everything will work.

Interesting, glad you figured it out. You should post that as an answer (and accept it) so others with similar issues see it too.
